# printing byte representation of std::string

Tags: c++, std

I am facing weird error while printing out byte representation of std::string while std::wstring works fine.

```
std::string str = "mystring";
unsigned short* vtemp = (unsigned short*)str.c_str();
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
{
    cout << (unsigned short)((unsigned char)vtemp[i]) << " ";
}
cout << endl;

Incorrect Output: 109 115 114 110 0 204 204 204


wstring wstr(str.length(), L' ');
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), wstr.begin());

vtemp = (unsigned short*)wstr.c_str();

for(int i=0; i<wstr.length(); ++i)
{
    cout << (unsigned short)((unsigned char)vtemp[i]) << " ";
}
cout << endl;

Correct Output: 109 121 115 116 114 105 110 103
```

In first case, every alternate character was skipped. Why so?

This program was run on windows with unicode character set enabled in project settings.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do‽ In the first place, you shouldn't be using C-style cast in C++. Than the fact that the result of `str.c_str()` won't `static_cast` to `unsigned short *`, but will require `reinterpret_cast` should tip you off that something is amiss. But in the first place, `std::string` can be both iterated with iterators and indexed; the use of pointers is totally superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```
unsigned short* vtemp = (unsigned short*)str.c_str();
```

`unsigned short` is two bytes long. `char` is one byte long. You are setting an `unsigned short` pointer to a `char` array and iterating by pointer indexing (every two bytes).

The compiler would normally tell you that, but your usage of C-style casts prevents that (because C-style casts fail silently).

Later edit: Your code also indexes an `unsigned short*` up to `str.length()` elements, but (the `short` being bigger than `char`) your array only contains `str.length() / 2` `unsigned short` indexable elements.

Running that code on some machines will probably result in a core-dump.

Comment: Ah! You're right. I am using a library function which needs to be passed string as (unsigned short*), so I guess I must use wstring version. (yes, segfault is expected in incorrect version)

Comment: @vivek.m: `short` and `wchar_t` are different types. Formally always, but on some systems they actually have different size. If you have function that wants `unsigned short *`, it wants `utf-16` explicitly and you have to ensure proper formatting yourself!

Comment: @JanHudec Correct. It's a windows-only API and for windows, wstring will be utf-16. Also, I do not know any easy way of ensuring wstring must be utf-16...tx.

Comment: *"`unsigned short` is two bytes long"*  Not necessarily.  All the Standard says is `sizeof(unsigned short) >= signed(char)`.

Comment: @vivek.m: You shouldn't get non-unicode `wchar_t` from anywhere. So the basic plane (codepoints less than 2^16) will always be correct. If `wchar_t` is 2-byte (as in Windows), extended plane (codepoints 2^16 and above) will either not be supported or be encoded as `utf-16`. If `wchar_t` is 4-byte (as in Linux), extended plane will be encoded directly (`ucs-4`) and you would have to use conversion routine. I suggest adding a [static assert](http://www.boost.org/libs/static_assert/) so you notice the problem if you ever try to port the code to a `ucs-4` platform.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using an `unsigned short` pointer, so every `++i` advances the pointer by `sizeof(unsigned short)` bytes. If on your platform `sizeof(unsigned short)==2`, as is likely, the first version would skip over every other character.

Answer (score 1):

wstring stores the raw data in two bytes format, while string stores it in one byte or simply char format. The moment you do (unsigned short *)str.c_str(), you are bounded to make jumps of two instead of one. While accessing the raw data of str you must use char* (even unsigned char* can lead to problems in my experience). so the right thing to do will be

```
const char *vtemp = str.c_str();
```

Answer (score 1):

A char is a byte, I don't see why you're casting the call to c_str() to an `unsigned short*`, when for one: the return value is not `unsigned` (could be for some platforms, depends how the compiler implements it) and for two, why not store what it returns temporarily and print it out with a cast (to see the numbers that it represents)?

The reason why it's "skipping" is because as I said std::string and std::wstring are defined like so:

Definition of std::string:
`typedef std::basic_string<char> std::string;`

Definition of std::wstring:
`typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> std::wstring;`

As you can see, they are not defined with an unsigned specifier. For std::string, c_str() returns a `const char*` and for std::wstring, c_str() returns a `const wchar_t*`.

Therefore, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "mystring";
    const char* vtemp = str.c_str();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
    {
        cout << (int)vtemp[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


    wstring wstr(str.length(), L' ');
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), wstr.begin());


    const wchar_t* wtemp = wstr.c_str();

    for(int i=0; i<wstr.length(); ++i)
    {
       cout << (int)wtemp[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short* vtemp = (unsigned short*)str.c_str();
```

Replace with:

```
unsigned char* vtemp = (unsigned char*)str.c_str();
```